# parameterized tests using Junit 5 in the "username" and "password" fields

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit5

I am writing a testing framework and I want to add parameterized tests using Junit 5 in the "username" and "password" fields. tell me how to do this on my example
Please tell me how to substitute different values instead of "awdawd@mail.ru" and " 123456789"

[image]

Comment: What is unclear from the Junit documentation?

Comment: Also, do you have different logic for different accounts? Otherwise, do you need to change the parameters?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I can't apply the code from the documentation to my case ,just show an example of how I can do it, I want to make positive tests and valid data and negative tests

Comment: Can you please show code instead of an image? And any attempt at the solution yourself? I don't see any `@ParameterizedTest` annotations in what you've shown or any errors that suggest you've tried unsuccessfully (saying you "can't" doesn't show how you know you can't)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I didn't write parameterized tests, because I don't understand how to write them, where (in what class), so I ask you to show an example of the test in my case)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to supply different argument sources, this one shows CsvSource for supplying pairs of user+passwords to a test:

```
public class TestWithParams
{
    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({
        "one@two.com,abc123"
        ,"three@four.com,xyz789"
    })
    void testWithLogin(String user, String password) {
        System.out.println("testWithLogin user="+user+" pass="+password);
    }
}
```

When run it prints:

```
testWithLogin user=one@two.com pass=abc123
testWithLogin user=three@four.com pass=xyz789
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

it was easier than I thought

```
 @ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({"awdwds@@mail.ru,           1234",
           "!smith@gmail.com,           987456",
            "login.mail.com,            12345 ",
            ".,/,star@yandex.ru,        123456"})
public void clickLoginTest(String login, String pass) {
    String acc = "Warning: No match for E-Mail Address and/or Password.";
    mainPage
            .goTo()
            .clickLogin();
    loginPage.logIntoAccount(login, pass);
    String textWrongLogIn = loginPage.getTextWrongLogIn();
    Assertions.assertEquals(acc, textWrongLogIn);
}
```